# Scala ignores imported members

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following code snippet:

```
package org.test.test.datahelper

import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql._

class WeatherHelper(sparkSession: SparkSession, weather: DataFrame) {

  def prepareRRRColumn: DataFrame = {
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions
    weather.withColumn("Year", year(col("DateTime")))

    weather
  }

}
```

The problem is that Scala (or probably IntelliJ IDEA) does not see method `year` just like `col` (`Cannot resolve symbol year` and `col` respectfully), despite the necessary import is just one line above (however, it doesn't work even if the import is global). Following to the source code of `org.apache.spark.sql.functions` I found the following lines:

```
def col(colName : scala.Predef.String) : org.apache.spark.sql.Column = { /* compiled code */ }
def year(e : org.apache.spark.sql.Column) : org.apache.spark.sql.Column = { /* compiled code */ }
```

i.e. both methods do exist. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sure, the problem can be solved in a following manner:
`def prepareRRRColumn: DataFrame = {`
`weather.withColumn("Year", org.apache.spark.sql.functions.year(
      org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col("DateTime")))`
     `weather`
  `}`
but it doesn't seem to be the best (or the only) solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a scala import syntax issue. 
To import the methods(col,year) within the class/package `function` you have to use.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
// Or import only specific functions 
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, year}
```

Instead of

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Such minor syntax differences between Java and Scala are confusing sometimes.

Comment: In Java you also can't use `year` and `col` after `import ...functions`, you'd write `functions.year`. And in Scala you can do the same.